# How to show or hide an element after clicking an input element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code. It works well when I use it with links or divs. But it doesn't work when I want to show or hide an element after clicking on an input. This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="row sec">
     <div class="large-3 columns">
     Select a subject
     </div>
     <div class="large-3 columns">
      <div class="radio science_b"><input type="radio" class="science_b" name="subject" value="Science" ><label for="subject"><span class="science_b"></span>Science</label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="large-3 columns">
      <div class="radio"><input type="radio" class="language_b" name="subject" value="Language" ><label for="subject"><span></span>Language</label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="large-3 columns">
      <div class="radio"><input type="radio" class="humanistic_b" name="subject" value="Humanistic" ><label for="subject"><span></span>Humanistic</label></div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="humanistic">
</div>
<div class="humanistic">
</div>
<div class="humanistic">
</div>
```

And this is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".science_b").click(function() {
          $(".science").show("slow", "swing");
          $(".humanistic").hide();
          $(".language").hide();
        });
        $(".language_b").click(function() {
          $(".language").hide();
          $(".science").show("slow", "swing");
          $(".humanistic").hide();
        });
        $(".humanistic_b").click(function() {
          $(".humanistic").show("slow", "swing");
          $(".language").hide();
          $(".science").hide();
        });
    });
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `.focus` https://api.jquery.com/focus/ for input text or `.change` for radio buttons or checkboxes and select

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWLmPR

Comment: After trying once and again and taking in account your comments, I realized that there was a problem with a plugin I was using with the form to stylize the buttons. I removed it, and it works. Thanks.

Comment: you should use .on() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying once and again and taking in account your comments, I realized that there was a problem with a plugin I was using with the form to stylize the buttons. I removed it, and it works. Thanks.